# How to remove the value and number labels from Highcharts angular gauge

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to remove the value box from a Highcharts angular gauge.

I'm not sure it is possible...I have tried messing around with the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-speedometer/) demo trying to remove it and haven't been able to.

I was able to remove the minor and major ticks by adding

```
minorTickInterval: 'none',
tickPixelInterval: 'none'
```

But I can't figure out how to remove the value from the middle of the gauge.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `dataLabels.formatter` to the `series` part of your gauge to remove it.

```
dataLabels: {
    formatter: function () {
        return null;
    }
},
```

Live example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hf9e70bc/)

Answer (score 3):

or you can achieve the result you want just by adding the following lines:

```
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
         enabled: false
    }
}]
```